# No sound from headphones. Ubuntu on iMac

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mac, audio, alsa

I have a fresh ubuntu on iMac. I have managed to set up the sound from the native speakers, however, there is still no sound from the headphones. I have disabled automute in alsamixer, but this didn't help. Does anyone know what to do in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was found by adding a row of `options snd-hda-intel model=imac27_122` to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` as explained [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12043359).

[image]

Comment: Worked for me as well! On Arch Linux, modprobe.d is usally empty, but just create a file, like `50-sound.conf` or similiar, and enter just that last line. I had `model=intel-mac-auto` in there before, which didn't work for me. iMac is a 27" from late 2012.